# Count number of lines in a AVRO file using python

Tags: python, avro

So currently i am able to open the avro file using:

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

reader = DataFileReader(open("myfile.avro", "r"), DatumReader())
for user in reader:
  print (user)
reader.close()
```

After this process, I would like to be able to count the number of lines in this file using python code.
I am currently using Python 2.7 through Spyder.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to count the number of lines? An avro file is in binary, there is not such thing as "line" in a binary file. An option would be to convert the avro file to a JSON like format [1] and then count the number of records (or lines, if you really want this).

[1] https://github.com/linkedin/python-avro-json-serializer

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
num_lines = sum(1 for line in reader)
```